# jQuery .insertAfter() copying input field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a html webpage here:

http://diagrams.inse1d.info/wbt.html

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WBT Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wbt.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wbt.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div id="wbtBlock">
                <p>Press enter to save amendments</p>
                <h1>Title of wbt:<input type="text" id="wbtTitle" /></h1>
                <div id="graph">
                    <p>Graph to go here</p>
                </div>
                <p><strong>Notes: </strong></p>
                <p><span><input type="textarea" id="wbtNote" /></span></p>
            </div> 
        </article>
    </section>
    <button>Add New WBT Chart</button>
</body>
```

Here is the jQuery code I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h1").keypress(function(e) {
    //get
    wbtTitle = $('#wbtTitle').val();
    // Write text after enter
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("h1").text(wbtTitle);
    }

});

$("span").keypress(function(e) {
    //get
    wbtNote = $('#wbtNote').val();
    // Write note after enter
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("span").text(wbtNote);
    }

});

//Insert new WBT on button click
$("button").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var wbtSet = $( "article" ).html();
        $(wbtSet).insertAfter('section');
    });
});
});
```

What I want to do is set the title and some note text using input boxes which works using jQuery. I then want to add a copy of the html into another article when the button is pressed without copying the inputs previously made with the possibility of setting new values when the article is cloned. The process should repeat over and over again.

Here is an image to help explain:
[image: Explanation]

I am quite new to jQuery, I think you need to use a loop to fix this, I read that a .each() can be used http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ but not quite sure.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe more detailed what it is you want to achieve? Right now I don't really understand what you want to do with your script.

Comment: Hi @Sebsemillia, I have updated the question. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Not quite I'm afraid. Right now your script is making a copy of the html in the article without the previously entered value of the inputs. Do you want to copy the content of the article tag without the input fields?

Comment: @Sebsemillia, I want to copy the content of the article without the value of the input fields previously set. I then want to be able to set new values. I have added an image to help explain, does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your answer.

I changed the html a bit, because you duplicated some id's with your approach, that's not good. id's have to be unique on a page. I simply changed them to classes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WBT Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wbt.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wbt.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="wbtBlock">
                <p>Press enter to save amendments</p>
                <h1>Title of wbt:<input type="text" class="wbtTitle" /></h1>
                <div class="graph">
                    <p>Graph to go here</p>
                </div>
                <p><strong>Notes: </strong></p>
                <p><span><input type="textarea" class="wbtNote" /></span></p>
            </div> 
        </article>
    </section>
    <button>Add New WBT Chart</button>
</body>
```

And of course the jQuery. I got rid of your first two functions because they had no purpose in this context.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Insert new WBT on button click
    $("button").on('click', function() {
        var title = $(this).prev().find('.wbtTitle').val();
        var note = $(this).prev().find('.wbtNote').val();
        var wbtSet = $(this).prev("section").html();       

        $(this).prev().find('.wbtTitle').replaceWith(title);
        $(this).prev().find('.wbtNote').replaceWith(note);

        $(this).prev("section").after('<section>' + wbtSet + '</section>');
    });
});
```

**Here is a working [fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/8s9Ng/6/)**

Comment: Thanks! this fixed this issue I was having and it works very well.

Comment: Glad I could help! But you should always take care of the id's and classes and the general markup in in your html projects, or you will run into problems sooner or later.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the answer given by hitokun_s

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Save a copy of the element wbtSet element on pageload
    var wbtSet = $("article").clone(); 
    $("button").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            // Append a new one to the holder of the wbSets
            $(wbtSet).appendTo($('section'));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This partially fixes the problem. When it is cloned, the input boxes stay there but when you enter text in the cloned input boxes and press enter, it does not update the <h1> or the <span> with the new values. It just stays blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do.

```
window.onload = function() {
            $("button").each(function() {
                $(this).click(function() {
                    var wbtSet = $("article:first-child").clone();
                    wbtSet.find("input").val("");
                    $(wbtSet).appendTo($('section'));
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: I added a semi colon at the end of this piece of code however it did not work. It wont allow me to put new values into the title and notes using the input boxes when the article is cloned..

Comment: I modified my answer. How about this?

Comment: Not quite, It clones the article, but does not allow me to edit the newly cloned article title or the notes. The input box disappears.

Comment: Oops, JelteF's answer is better.Thank you JelteF!